# In Java, one of my alert boxes is showing twice and the nested alert box is not showing at all

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am working on a school project where I am working with a mySQL database. The specific part I'm working on right now is what happens when a user of the system attempts to delete an appointment from the database. I have three alerts, one works, one is presenting twice, and the other isn't working at all. The first loop, the one that verifies a choice is selected does work. The second one that confirms if the user wants to delete runs twice, i.e. when you click the OK button it shows again and you must click again. Then, it seems to skip to the bottom where I reload the page. When it reloads the page I can see that the appointment was successfully deleted and it also shows as deleted in the mysql work bench. So it's only the middle alert that doesn't seem to run at all. I have scoured the internet to find out why one is showing twice and the other not at all and although I have found similar questions and problems I tried using their solutions and I did not see any difference. I appreciate any help in the right direction be it code correction or resources! Thank you very much in advance.

```
// delete selected appointment
    @FXML
    void handleDelete(MouseEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Appointment ifSelected = appointmentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


    if (ifSelected == null){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Deletion Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("You didn't choose an appointment to delete.");
        alert.setContentText("Please click ok in order to choose an appointment for deletion.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Appointment Deletion");
        alert.setHeaderText("You are about to delete an appointment record permanantly.");
        alert.setContentText("If you want to proceed, click ok.");

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
            Alert alert2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert2.setTitle("Deletion Successful");
            alert2.setHeaderText("You successfully deleted the appointment with " + ifSelected.getCustomerName()+ " at " + ifSelected.getStartTime() + ".");
            alert.setContentText("If you want to proceed, click ok.");
            alert.show();


            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            apptID = ifSelected.getAppointmentID();
            String sqlDeleteAppointment = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE appointmentId = " + apptID;
            Query.makeQuery(sqlDeleteAppointment);


            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("appointmentScreen.fxml"));
            scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

    }
}}
```

'''

Comment: There is a typo in your code. You are using `alert` rather than `alert2` to show your third alert after pressing OK button. This is one of the reason why you should always give proper names to your variable.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cassandra Do mark the correct answers, it will help others..

Answer (score 1):

You have created alert2 object from Alert class for your nested Alerts. But you have used **alert** object instead of **alert2**.

```
Alert alert2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert2.setTitle("Deletion Successful");
alert2.setHeaderText("You successfully deleted the appointment with " + ifSelected.getCustomerName()+ " at " + ifSelected.getStartTime() + ".");
alert2.setContentText("If you want to proceed, click ok.");
alert2.show();
```